# Memcache warnings in Drupal6

Tags: php, apache, drupal, memcached, suppress-warnings

I've got a Drupal site running with memcached. In case the server reboots, memcached is stopped and Drupal spits out a lot of warnings on the screen.

Whilst looking at the way to get memcache started when the server reboots, my main concern here is to include a conditional in my Drupal settings, in case memcached is not found.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be hiding all warnings from users anyway.

```
error_reporting(0);
```

Comment: not really the answer i'm looking for... i'm already hiding the warnings